# Get only the Changed data from angular2 forms

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Hie.I have a basic angular2 forms where i have nested objects.What i am trying to make is that i want to get only those fields which are dirty.I am facing problem to get the values of deeply nested objects...This is my demo http://plnkr.co/edit/gzT4mVWglHrFziRayHtK?p=preview ,here changes done in Contacts fields are coming in main Object...

```
{
"addressinfo": {
"Line1": "",
"Line2": ""
},
"firstname": "",
"lastname": "",
"Contacts": {
"Phone1": {
  "Type": "",
  "Number": ""
}
}
}
```

If I change Number Field and submit the form then I am getting the response object in this way...

```
{
"Contacts": {},
"Phone1": {
  "Number": ""
}
}
```

Since Number field has been changed i want the output to be in this way

```
{
"Contacts": {
     "Phone1": {
        "Number": ""
     }
   },
}
```

Somebody help me to get only the changed data in the right object format...Thanks

Comment: Have you checked it properly. I can find `Number,Type` inside `myForm`.

Comment: What you have done so far is good. Controls have other properties too. So I think your plunker good only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to step through your code in a debug session (by using the [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement for example)? When it is checking your `Contacts` control group it pushes this name as new object onto the `ResultObject` and starts executing `recursivelyIterateProperties(jsonObject,ResultObject,activeProperty)` again, with the following parameters:

```
jsonObject = {Phone1: ControlGroup},
ResultObject = {Contacts: {}},
activeProperty = 'Contacts'
```

The problem is that `Phone1` is again a control group and therefore your `=== 'object'` code is executed again, pushing a new `Phone1` object directly onto the `ResultObject`. In other words, your code doesn't handle nested control groups very well.

I have taken the liberty to rewrite your code a bit into a working example: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yYGNY1wW09jtlKJzSzx3?p=preview).

For clarity the iteration over the initial control groups has been split from the collection of the values. We first iterate over all controls:

```
iterateOverControls(controls, resultObject): any {
  var resultObject = {};
  // Iterate over controls and controlgroups
  for ( var control in controls ) {
    var result = {}
    // Only look into dirty controls
    if ( controls.hasOwnProperty(control) && !controls[control].pristine ) {
      result[control] = this.retrieveValuesForControl(controls[control]);
      // Once we have collected the changes, add them to the result object
      for ( var key in result ) {
        if ( result.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
          resultObject[key] = result[key];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return resultObject;
}
```

For each control that we encounter, we try to collect its values by calling `retrieveValuesForControl`. This method expects the control we are currently looking into as a parameter.

```
retrieveValuesForControl(control): any {
  // Only check dirty objects
  if ( control.pristine ) {
    return;
  }

  var values;
  if ( typeof(control.value) === 'object' && control.controls ) {
    // The current control is a control group, so we need to look deeper
    values = {};
    for ( var item in control.controls ) {
      // We retrieve values for this control again (recursively)
      values[item] = this.retrieveValuesForControl(control.controls[item]);
    }
  } else if ( !control.pristine) {
    // We have a control, so copy the value
    values = control.value;
  }

  // Return our collected values (either a plain value or object of values)
  return values;
}
```

In this method we first check if the control we are looking at is dirty. If it is pristine, we return directly. Next we check if we are looking at a control group or a control.

- In case of a control group: we want to look into the control group again by calling `iterateOverControls` for each and every control that the control group contains. The results of these calls are collected, put into one object and returned when we are done.
- In case of a control: we can collect the value an return it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are not able to find them properly.

```
console.log(this.myForm.controls.Contacts.controls.Phone1.controls);
```

This is the exact way where you can find Number and Type. I don't see any problem in your plunker.

Comment: the iteration of objects in an object works fine and it is recognizing the changed field perfectly, but when i try to get the response changed fields the output should look in this format `{
"Contacts": {
     "Phone1": {
        "Number": ""
     }
   },
}`   For that i am trying ,dono how to get the response in that way

Answer (score 0):

You can also subscribe to

this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(...)

and collect changed values this way.